# Xcode5 changes static table behavoir. How to fix?

Tags: ios, xcode, uitableview, ios7, xcode5

This block of code worked perfectly in Xcode 4.6 but no longer works in Xcode5/IOS7.

Depending on the ID rows within a section are visible or not visible (along with the section header) in a static table.  The view controller will load if the code below is commented out otherwise it generates: Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: '*** -[__NSArrayI objectAtIndex:]: index 1 beyond bounds [0 .. 0]'

View controller is a UITableView with everything but numberOfRowsInSection commented out.

Any thoughts how to get this functionality back?

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    if(section == 1)
    {
        if(ID == 1) return 0;
        else return 1;
    }
    else return 2;
}
```

Thanks

Solved!!!  Replaced the "else return 2" with:

```
else return [super tableView:tableView numberOfRowsInSection:section];
```

Answer (score 0):

Your standard number of rows is 2. You must be assuming somewhere else in your code, that you can access the second row (with index 1) even if you return 0 or 1 for your section with index 1.

That would explain why your code leads to this error and does not otherwise.